# Auto coloring in text area in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a code editor.
Just a simple one.
Was wondering how can I style the text inside a `<textarea>` without the need of using `<span class="function"></span>` for example
since the text is constantly updating..
using either pure (javascript or css) (no jquery or libraries please)
Thanks for any advices

Comment: What did you tried so far ? Can you add your code please ?

Comment: don't re-invent the wheel. this is probably going to much more difficult than you think. google for syntax highlighters there are tons out there that you can implement just by including a script.

Comment: Try https://highlightjs.org/

Comment: I'm asking for an advice.. not re-inventing...

Comment: why can't you write css styles inside `textarea` selector. Am i missing something ?

Comment: and haven't coded yet..
I'm doing this for practice wise..

Answer (score 1):

`textarea` support `oninput` event, which fires every time you type in it. For example:

```
<textarea oninput="testFunction()"></textarea>
<script>
function testFunction() {
    console.log("input has changed");
}
</script>
```

This should give you a head start in writing the vanilla JS code you need.

Comment: Thank you so much!
appreciate it.. dunno why these people have so much hate !

Comment: @ItachiSama it's not hate, it's the idea of SO that questions should not be too broad and too abstract. Since the community is self-managing, other people appreciate when you ask precise questions like "here's my code, what am I doing wrong?"

Comment: It was really an advise to where I should step on.. like read this link to get started for example...

Answer (score 0):

Have you even tryed to do it?

You can do it as easy and just add `style="color: orange;` In your `<textarea>` like so:

```
<textarea style="color: orange;"></textarea>
```

Or you can add it in css like so:

```
textarea {
    color: orange;
}
```

You can style it to what EVER, you want inside the `textarea { }` in css.

Answer (score -1):

Put this in your CSS:

```
    textarea {
    font-family: arial;
}
```

you can change the font family to whatever you want